# Define filetypes that get indexed in a specific folder

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 Explorer I have setup a new library called Tools. How can I tell Windows 7 that in that folder only executable files should be indexed? Currently when I type the name of one of the tools into the startmenu, it lists all the DLLs, config files etc. with the same name too (often there are a lot of files that contain the name of the executable).

Comment: What is the behavior that you are looking for? Just getting a list of the .exe files?

Comment: yes, for that specific library only, I would like to only get the list of exe files (and maybe also all other executable filetypes like .bat, .com ...)

Comment: Why don't you just search for *.exe, *.bat, etc?

Comment: You mean search in the start menu? If I enter "*.exe" there, I will get billions of result. I would like to be able to quicky launch a program that is somewhere in the Tools directory. I really wouldn't want to enter `AveryLongToolFileName.exe` just to filter out all `AveryLongToolFileName.*.DLL` files. I am always only interested in executable files within Tools.

Comment: No, I mean search in windows explorer. Navigate to tools, then search.

Comment: The whole idea behind this question is to start tools quickly with just a view keystrokes.